# Rspec is giving file is not defined error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

My code is here

```
require 'spec_helper'
describe file('/home/ravendra/backup.sh') do
  its(:content) { should match /^ip=[$]1/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^ssh_port=[$]2/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^user=[$]3/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^TIMESTAMP=`date \S%y-%m-%d\w%H-%M-%S`/ }  
  its(:content) { should match /^sh \/root\/backup_scripts\/openstack_backup.sh/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^sh \/root\/backup_scripts\/dashboard_backup.sh/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^tar -czvf musashi_backup-[$]TIMESTAMP.tar.gz \/musashi_backup/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^backup_remote_server \(\) {/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^rsync -rvaz --progress -e "ssh -p [$]ssh_port" musashi_backup-[$]TIMESTAMP.tar.gz [$]user@(.*?).(.*?).(.*?):(~)\// }
  its(:content) { should match /^rsync -rvaz --progress -e "ssh -p [$]ssh_port" \/root\/backup_scripts\/restore.sh [$]user@(.*?).(.*?).(.*?):(~)\// }
  its(:content) { should match /^}/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^if \[ "[$]#" -eq 3 \]; then/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^backup_remote_server/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^fi/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^rsync -rvaz --progress musashi_backup-[$]TIMESTAMP.tar.gz \/musashi_backup\// }
  its(:content) { should match /^rsync -rvaz --progress \/root\/backup_scripts\/restore.sh \/musashi_backup\// }
end

describe file('/home/ravendra/backup_server.sh') do
  its(:content) { should match /^ip=[$]1/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^ssh_port=[$]2/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^user=[$]3/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^TIMESTAMP=`date \S%y-%m-%d\w%H-%M-%S`/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^is_IP \(\) {/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^local stat=1/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^if \[\[ [$]ip =~ ^\[0-9\]{1,3}\\.\[0-9\]{1,3}\\.\[0-9\]{1,3}\\.\[0-9\]{1,3}[$] \]\]; then/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^OIFS=[$]IFS/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^IFS='.'/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^ip=\([$]ip\)/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^IFS=[$]OIFS/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^\[\[ [$]{ip\[0\]} -le 255 && [$]{ip\[1\]} -le 255 \\/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^&& [$]{ip\[2\]} -le 255 && [$]{ip\[3\]} -le 255 \]\]/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^stat=[$]?/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^echo [$]stat/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^fi/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^return [$]stat/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^}/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^ip_ping \(\) {/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^if \[\[ [$]\(ping -q -c3 [$]ip\) == @\(*100% packet loss*\) \]\]; then/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^echo "Unable to Ping the given Host"/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^echo "Note : Please check the value of 'kernel parameter net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all' at the location '\/proc\/sys\/net\/ipv4\/'.\\/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^If it's value is 1 then it will prevent other host from successfully pinging your server.In such case change it's \\/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^value to 0 for successful pinging. Please try again."/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^else/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^ssh_validation/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^fi/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^}/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^is_ssh_port \(\) {/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^nc -z -w 3 [$]ip [$]ssh_port/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^if \[ "[$]?" -ne 0 \]; then/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^echo "Connection to" [$]ip "on port" [$]ssh_port "failed. Please try again."/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^else/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^echo "Connection to" [$]ip "on port" [$]ssh_port "succeeded"/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^backup_server/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^fi/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^}/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^backup_server \(\) {/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^tar -czvf musashi_backup-[$]TIMESTAMP.tar.gz \/musashi_backup/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^rsync -rvaz --progress -e "ssh -p [$]ssh.port" musashi_backup-[$]TIMESTAMP.tar.gz [$]user@(.*?).(.*?).(.*?):(~)\// }
  its(:content) { should match /^rsync -rvaz --progress -e "ssh -p [$]ssh.port" \/root\/backup_scripts\/restore.sh [$]user@(.*?).(.*?).(.*?):(~)\// }
  its(:content) { should match /^create_cron/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^}/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^ip_validation \(\) {/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^return_val=[$]\(is_IP\)/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^if \[ "[$]return_val" == 0 \]; then/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^ip_ping/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^elif \[ "[$]return_val" == 1 \]; then/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^echo "IP address should be in range of 0 to 255"/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^else/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^echo "Please put a valid IP addres"/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^fi/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^}/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^is_ssh \(\) {/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^local stat=1/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^if \[\[ [$]ssh_port =~ ^\(\[0-9\]{1,4}\|\[1-5\]\[0-9\]{4}\|6\[0-4\]\[0-9\]{3}\|65\[0-4\]\[0-9\]{2}\|655\[0-2\]\[0-9\]\|6553\[0-5\]\)[$] \]\]; then/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^stat=[$]?/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^echo [$]stat/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^fi/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^return [$]stat/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^}/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^ssh_validation \(\) {/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^return_val=[$]\(is_ssh\)/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^if \[ "[$]return_val" == 0 \]; then/ } 
  its(:content) { should match /^is_ssh_port/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^else/ } 
  its(:content) { should match /^echo "Please put a valid SSH port number. It should be in range of 0 to 65535."/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^fi/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^}/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^ create_cron \(\) {/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^\( crontab -l \| grep -v \/root\/backup_scripts\/backup.sh \) \| crontab -/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^crontab -l \| { cat; echo "0 1 * * * \/root\/backup_scripts\/backup.sh [$]ip [$]ssh_port [$]user"; } \| crontab -/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^}/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^if \[ "[$]#" -eq 3 \]; then/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^ip_validation/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^else/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^echo "Please provide valid number of arguments."/ }
  its(:content) { should match /^fi/ }
end
```

but when i run with `rspec spec/rootfiles_spec.rb` it gives us

```
/home/ravendra/Documents/rails-project/pif_form/spec/rootfiles_spec.rb:2:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `file' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
from /home/ravendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1058:in `load'
from /home/ravendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1058:in `block in load_spec_files'
from /home/ravendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1058:in `each'
from /home/ravendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1058:in `load_spec_files'
from /home/ravendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:97:in `setup'
from /home/ravendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in `run'
from /home/ravendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
from /home/ravendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
from /home/ravendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/rspec-core-3.0.4/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/ravendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
from /home/ravendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
from /home/ravendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /home/ravendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Some one help me

Comment: where do you see a method called file on the rspec docs?

Comment: @Anthony I need to match a file with the same content so I include all file

Comment: This is not standard RSpec syntax. Are you using serverspec by chance? http://serverspec.org/resource_types.html#file

Answer (score 4):

The error message is telling you that there is no `file` method in RSpec. And, if you look at the documentation of RSpec, you will see, that there is indeed no `file` method in RSpec.

So, you have to either write one or install some library which has one.